# Understanding CSRF

Tags: security, session, csrf

I don't understand how using a 'challenge token' would add any sort of prevention: what value should compared with what?

From [OWASP](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet):

> In general, developers need only
>   generate this token once for the
>   current session. After initial
>   generation of this token, the value is
>   stored in the session and is utilized
>   for each subsequent request until the
>   session expires.

If I understand the process correctly, this is what happens.

I log in at http://example.com and a session/cookie is created containing this random token. Then, every form includes a hidden input also containing this random value from the session which is compared with the session/cookie upon form submission.

But what does that accomplish? Aren't you just taking session data, putting it in the page, and then comparing it with the exact same session data? Seems like circular reasoning. These articles keep talking about following the "same-origin policy" but that makes no sense, because all CSRF attacks ARE of the same origin as the user, just tricking the user into doing actions he/she didn't intend.

Is there any alternative other than appending the token to every single URL as a query string? Seems very ugly and impractical, and makes bookmarking harder for the user.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The attacker has no way to get the token. Therefore the requests won't take any effect.

I recommend this post from Gnucitizen. It has a pretty decent CSRF explanation: http://www.gnucitizen.org/blog/csrf-demystified/

Comment: Nowadays we have new defence approach "SameSite" Cookie attribute, but while it not supported by all browsers https://caniuse.com/#feat=same-site-cookie-attribute. Moreover all possible protection methods could be found here https://web-security.guru/en/attacks/csrf/prevention

Answer (score 25):

### CSRF Explained with an analogy - Example:

- You open the front door of your house with a key.
- Before you go inside, you speak to your neighbour
- While you are having this conversation, an attacker walks in, while the door is still unlocked.
- They go inside, pretending to be you!
- Nobody inside your house notices anything different - your wife is like, ‘oh crud*, he’s home’.

The impersonator helps himself to all of your money etc

#### Summary

CSRF basically relies on the fact that you opened the door to your house and then left it open, allowing someone else to simply walk in and pretend to be you.

#### What is the way to solve this problem?

When you first open the door to your house, you are given a paper with a long and very random number written on it by your door man:

> "ASDFLJWERLI2343234"

Now, if you wanna get into your own house, you have to present that piece of paper to the door man to get in.

So *now* when the impersonator tries to get into your house, the door man asks:

"What is the random number written on the paper?"

If the impersonator doesn't have the correct number, then he won't get in. Either that or he must guess the random number correctly - which is a very difficult task. What's worse is that the random number is valid for only 20 minutes (e.g). So know the impersonator must guess correctly, and not only that, he has only 20 minutes to get the right answer. That's way too much effort! So he gives up.

Granted, the analogy is a little strained, but I hope it is helpful to you.

#### Applied Example

If you are logged into your bank, and then go to a different website, e.g. "www.bad_guy_banking_attacker.com" it is possible that you may click a form on that site that makes a POST request transferring money out of your bank account to the bad guy's account. Because you've already logged in, the bank's server may authorize the transaction. Hopefully your bank's server has implemented CSRF protection. The bad guy will need to have a token issued by the bank, within his malicious form. He won't have that token - or he will have to guess correctly. However, when you legitimately access your bank's web page, all forms within that page will have the token. Hence when that form is submitted, the server can check the veracity of the token.

If that is confusing, just think of the doorman analogy. Perhaps I will return one day and add a diagram to make it clear, if reader demand warrants it.

**crud = (Create, Read, Updated Delete)

Comment: haha, nicely illustrated!

Answer (score 13):

You need to keep researching this topic for your self, but I guess that's why you are posting to SO :).  [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Csrf) is a very serious and widespread vulnerability type that all web app developers should be aware of.

First of all,  there is more than one [same origin policy](http://code.google.com/p/browsersec/wiki/Part2#Same-origin_policy).  But the most important part is that a script being hosted from http://whatever.com cannot READ data from http://victom.com,  but it can SEND data via POST and GET.   If the request only contains information that is known to the attacker,  then the attacker can forge a request on the victom's browser and send it **anywhere**.  Here are 3 [XSRF exploits](http://milw0rm.com/exploits/7389) that are building requests that do not contain a random token.

If the site contains a random token then you have to use XSS to bypass the protection that the Same Origin Policy provides.  Using XSS you can force javascript to "originate" from another domain, then it can use XmlHttpRequest to read the token and forge the request.  Here is an [exploit](http://milw0rm.com/exploits/7922) I wrote that does just that.

Answer (score 9):

> Is there any alternative other than
> appending the token to every single
> URL as a query string? Seems very ugly
> and impractical, and makes bookmarking
> harder for the user.

There is no reason to append the token to every URL on your site, *as long as* you ensure that all GET requests on your site are read-only. If you are using a GET request to modify data on the server, you'd have to protect it using a CSRF token.

The funny part with CSRF is that while an attacker can make any http request to your site, he cannot read back the response.

If you have GET urls without a random token, the attacker will be able to make a request, but he won't be able to read back the response. If that url changed some state on the server, the attacker's job is done. But if just generated some html, the attacker has gained nothing, and you have lost nothing.

Image: [sample image CSRF attack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulaRS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) is an attack where a third party forces a user to execute actions against a site where they are currently logged in.

Example:

You visit traveltrip.com.
traveltrip.com has a hidden form that submits on page load to myaccount.com/transfer-funds. Since you are logged in to myaccount.com, this request is made with your myaccount.com cookies and will silently initiate a money transfer out of your account.
Since 'traveltrip.com' and 'myaccount.com' are different origins, the browser refuses to provide the response to traveltrip.com (because of CORS), but the attacker doesn't care, the money's already been transferred.
Now if myaccount.com implements CSRF protection correctly:

Each time myaccount.com serves a form to a user, it generates a CSRF token and inserts it into a hidden field in the form.
If a POST request is received, it checks the CSRF token against its database - if this is present and valid then the request goes through. If the CSRF token is missing or incorrect it is rejected.
CSRF attacks target state-changing requests and not the direct theft of data because the attacker does not see the response of the forged request.

[Sample image CSRF attack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQApN.png)