# Prevent spam bots php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, bots, spam, traffic

I have a forum with lots of buttons  `<button class="vote" data-id="10">Vote up</button>` the data-id relates to my thread id of `MySQL` table.

It can happen as a bot will automatically run the below js and send post request with several random data-id overloading the server.  How can I prevent this?

```
//on click vote
$.post('vote. Php', {
data-id : data-id 
}
```

Php

```
$userid=$_SESSION['userid'] ;
//take data-id and insert into mysql
```

Comment: I recommend reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581488/understanding-csrf-simple-question

Comment: captcha codes, hidden input tokens, or even simply put cookies for which user voted-up which data-id

Comment: For simple spambots, you can just require JavaScript to be run to complete the voting. It seems you are already doing that, so you are probably being spammed by a headless browser-based (e.g. PhantomJS-based) spambot. You can either try to detect a headless browser, or use a human challenge like a CAPTCHA.