# CodeIgniter CSRF Server-Side Implementation?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, csrf

During some basic security test. When the apache request sent with **same custom** `header-CSRF-cookie` and `POST-CSRF-Cookie`.

CSRF token get validated and request is processed.

I have gone through the implementation.

```
$valid = isset($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name], $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])
            && is_string($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name]) && is_string($_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])
            && hash_equals($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name], $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name]);
```

Both verifying data is from client-side.

**hash_equals($_POST[$this->_csrf_token_name], $_COOKIE[$this->_csrf_cookie_name])**

Is there any purpose that CodeIgniter implementation in this ways.

Does anyone tried to implement it in **session** instead of **cookie**?

Comment: What you need to do? Question is not clear

Comment: Instead of storing CSRF token in client side cookie. I want it to store in session variable.

Comment: You are not understanding the principles behind CSRF - Here is some reading on the matter - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581488/understanding-csrf

Comment: HI @TimBrownlaw . In CodeIgniter the token is generated with **md5 hashing**. md5 is 32 char length, right. But I sent a cookie with token with only 5 digit and post token same 5 digit. The process is successfully completed without any issue. But I think the process has to be stopped in this case.